# fuzzy regex matching in julia

Tags: julia, fuzzy-comparison

Is there a way to do fuzzy regex matching in Julia?

I have constructed the following regular expression test:

```
toMatch = Regex(word,"i")
ismatch(toMatch,input_string)
```

I would like to be able to do this test but allow for some latitude in the matching and to specify this by Levenshtein distance.

I have found the package Levenshtein which can calculate the distance but am not sure how to incorporate it into this logic. For example:

```
levenshtein("hello","hllo")`
> 1
```

Comment: Do you need regex here? This sounds like a hard (computationally) problem for general regular expressions.

Comment: It's possible that I don't need it. I first solved this problem for exact matches using the code listed here and now am trying to allow accepting of misspellings within **input_string**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer has nothing to do with regular expressions, but it covers some use cases.)

I don't know if this works for your use case. But it looks like you are trying to find whether a word (or a close misspelling) is in your text. If the text is separated by spaces, and your word does not contain spaces, you could try something like:

```
nopunct(s) = filter(c -> !ispunct(c), s)
nfcl(s) = normalize_string(s, decompose=true, compat=true, casefold=true,
                              stripmark=true, stripignore=true)
canonicalize(s) = nopunct(nfcl(s))
fuzzy(needle, haystack, n) = any(
    w -> levenshtein(w, canonicalize(needle)) < n,
    split(canonicalize(haystack)))
```

What this does is, roughly:

`nfcl` normalizes strings with similar "human" appearances, by stripping out accents, ignoring case, and performing unicode normalization. This is pretty useful for fuzzy matching:

```
julia> nfcl("Ce texte est en français.")
"ce texte est en francais."
```

`nopunct` strips punctuation characters, further simplifying the string.

```
julia> nopunct("Hello, World!")
"Hello World"
```

`canonicalize` simply combines these two transformations.

Then we check whether any of the words in the haystack (split by whitespace) are within `n` of the needle.

Examples:

```
julia> fuzzy("Robert", "My name is robrt.", 2)
true

julia> fuzzy("Robert", "My name is john.", 2)
false
```

This is by no means a complete solution, but it covers a lot of common use cases. For more advanced use cases, you should look into [the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) in more depth.

Comment: This is very helpful, however, in my case the word that I am trying to find in my text may have spaces in it as it could be a phrase. Are there any modifications to this that you could suggest that might be adapted?

Comment: @Aaron If the needle is a plain old string (no regex characters like `*` or `()`), there is a "trick" you could do: compute `levenshtein(needle, haystack)` and check if it is less than `length(haystack) - length(needle) + n`. (At least `length(haystack) - length(needle)` characters must be deleted to get from the haystack to the needle, then possibly up to `n` further operations.) This works regardless of what characters are in the needle.

Comment: I think this is going to work out extremely well for my needs. One modification I will add is to vary `n` slightly as a function of the `length of needle`.

Comment: Thank you @FengyangWang.  @Aaron, good call.  I personally used `fuzzy(needle, haystack, round(Int, length(needle) * (3/4)))`.